# Fix multiple grub loads

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

On my laptop I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10.
After having messed up a little my Ubuntu installation, I decided to install a new 17.10 from scratch, formatting the root partition and keeping my home partition.

The installation went well, I can boot both Ubuntu and Windows, but when Grub is running it seems to load more than once: a first black background menu is loaded, then a purple background one, then again the black one and finally the purple one.
The rows on the purple and black menus seem to be the same. I get the same kind of event when I choose the advanced options for Ubuntu in the menu.

You can find the output of boot-repair summary here

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J4jwKpjDzt/

while here you can have a glimpse of the transition between the black and purple menu

http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l501/zizzus/boot_zpsv1kzk0xm.jpg

How can I fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: You are showing a grub.d folder inside your /etc/grub.d? Is that some how also then executed? Note sure you should even have that folder.

Comment: @oldfred: if you mean line 84 of the output of boot-repair, it should be just a description of /etc/grub.d. There is not any nested grub.d folder inside grub.d folder, just checked.

Comment: It is showing with a d as first char, or a directory. `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 mar  4 10:49 grub.d`

Comment: @oldfred: running `ls -a /etc/grub.d` I get `.  ..  00_header  05_debian_theme  10_linux  20_linux_xen  20_memtest86+  30_os-prober  30_uefi-firmware  40_custom  41_custom  README`

Comment: I went back and looks at my Boot-Repair and it is the same, it shows directly first. But your issue is like it is running grub scripts more than once. I might try a total purge of grub and reinstall of grub with Boot-Repair's advanced options, just to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: This thread may be related? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386182&p=13745234#post13745234